# why click on the button is not working on IE?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm just preparing the release of a library site builded in asp.net:

http://213.133.103.5/gramma_prod/Site/Index.aspx

All it's working great on FF and Chrome but on IE the asp button click event is not working.
Please notice the most important buttons: "Adauga in cos" (Add to basket)...

I'm just struggling to find out the problem...

I've checked the forms to not have nested ones but they seems ok.

Could you provide any other ideea?

ps: I did not post any code because this problem occurs on all pages...

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Code for "Add to basket"(Adauga in cos) button from the index:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnCosBooksFeatured" runat="server" 
OnCommand="addProductToBasket_Click"
CommandName="Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Carti_id").ToString()+","+Eval("Titlu").ToString()+","+Eval("Autor").ToString()%>'                                                       
ImageUrl="../Site/images/featured-cos.jpg" ToolTip="Adauga in cos" />
```

- works ok on ff and chrome. Fails on IE :(

Comment: I checked your link and I clicked add to basket, it worked !! I am on IE8

Comment: Strange..for me it does not work for IE6, 7 or 8...

Comment: There are a couple of links on that page and one of them didn't work for me (the blue button with the image of the little cart) and I'm using IE7.

Comment: Yes, that is the image button with the problem...In english "Add to Cart"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!!

What a stupid thing: i had a user control for the header which contained a form tag. So basically, my index contained two form tags because the user control was included as well....Auchhhhhh!

Comment: just was writing  it, but triple reread your post: "I've checked the forms to not have nested ones but they seems ok." :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, your button, have the click event, and enable post back?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any onclick event... here is the source. Am I missing something?

```
<div class="adauga">
<input type="image" name="Repeater2$ctl00$imgBtnCosBooksFeatured" id="Repeater2_ctl00_imgBtnCosBooksFeatured" title="Adauga in cos" src="../Site/images/featured-cos.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />
</div>
```